# Find smallest and biggest vector on line

Tags: javascript, vector, 2d

I have a line with multiple 2D vectors on it:

[1,1]
[4,4]
[-2,-2]
[-3,-3]

[image: how to calculate the smallest and biggest vector?]

How can i get the 'smallest' vector and the 'biggest vector? 
(i want the blue ones on the picture)

In javascript my array looks like this:

```
var vectors = [
   {
      x: 1,
      y: 1
   }
   {
      x: 4,
      y: 4
   }
   {
      x: -2,
      y: -2
   }
   {
      x: -3,
      y: -3
   }

];
```

I've already tried to get the magnitude of the vectors but since the magnitude is always positive it can't work that way:

```
this.x = Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
this.y = 0;
```

Comment: Convert to polar coordinates, and pick the biggest magnitudes on either side of the y axis.

Comment: And don't write "/" between coordinates, it looks like fractions.

Comment: is smallest/largest means leftmost/rightmost point ? in all the cases ..?

Comment: @SarathSaleem no. It means the two with the biggest distance to (0,0) in both directions of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one of your vector and compute the scalar product with all the vectors (including the one you chose) the min and max of this array will correspond to the extremal points on the line.